# How to open a text file in python 3.0

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, file

Hey So i typed in this code:

```
opennote = open('C:\\Users\\My_username\\coolnotepad.txt')
```

(with my username ofc)
yet i keep getting this

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Helpp!

Comment: could we see more of your code?

Comment: Is there a variable named 'open'?

Comment: sounds like you have assigned `open` to a variable

Comment: I did it on the interactive shell so this is all i have. "Automate the boring stuff with python"(The book) Has the same example, and it works

Comment: `print(type(open))` in your shell. You should get `<class 'builtin_function_or_method'>`. If you don't then your environment or your previous code has redefined `open` as a string

Answer (score 2):

A `callable` has a `__call__` method defined, meaning you can follow it with `()` to invoke its functionality.

`open` is a reserved keyword, which, if overridden by a variable, shows the behavior you are seeing.

Using a text editor that supports the python syntax with highlighting can help you avoid issues like this.

Comment: I did the same on pycahrm and it works! thanks. How come it doesn't work on the interactive shell?

Comment: @Skulli01 `print(type(open))` in your shell. You should get `<class 'builtin_function_or_method'>`. If you don't, then your environment or your previous code has redefined `open` as a string

Comment: yeah it says (class,str), i did this: open = ('C:\\Users\\Suraj Kalidindi\\hyeyyy') so it didnt work. thanks a ton :)

Comment: Please consider accepting this answer if it works for you @Skulli01